# SQL server views and datetime

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, view

```
select
    traceid, CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),serialnumber)) serialnumber, 
    product_prod_week, 
    LEFT(product_prod_week,4)+'00' + month(dateadd(wk,right(product_prod_week,2) -1,
    LEFT( product_prod_week,4) + '/01/01'))  as product_prod_month, 
    isnull(product_prod_date,s.century_proddate) product_prod_date
from
    mq m join serialdate s on m.product_prod_week= s.century_serdat
    /*This part is restricting view to 36 months only*/
where
    LEFT( product_prod_week,4)+'00' +month(dateadd(wk,right(product_prod_week,2) -1,
    LEFT( product_prod_week,4) + '/01/01'))  between  substring(Replace(DATEADD(month,-37, DATEADD(month,-1,convert(date,getdate()))),'-',''),1,6)
    and substring(replace(DATEADD(month,-1,convert(date,getdate())),'-',''),1,6)
```

The above is a view. view_mq. I have been banging my head over this from last many hours but can't find the issue.

```
    select count(* )from view_mq 
    select COUNT(*)  from view_mq where isdate(product_prod_date)=0
```

gives me this error -
**The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.**

**Where is the conversion happening? I don't understand.**

1. serialdate table is has century_proddate column as datetime.
2. product_prod_date in mq is datetime format.
3. Rest are in char/varchar type.

Comment: As a bit of a root cause analysis here, why are you doing so much string manipulation to get your dates?

Comment: I can't believe I found the answer myself! Product_prod_week had letter 'd' and that was causing the problem. We cna consider this answered:)

Comment: @iamdave because I need to convert weeks to months and restrcit the data based on number of months. :)

Comment: Look at using either `dateadd` and `datediff` logic or a `Dates` table to get month and week values.  For example, `dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,YourDate),0)` will get the start of the month for `YourDate`, which you can then `group` on as an actual `date` value.